# Keycloak-admin-client JAVA API get 404 not-found

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-admin-client

I am trying to get all scope-permissions for a client using an admin client.
I am using keycloak 12.0.4, spring-boot and keycloak-admin-client maven dependency.

The client i am using has realm-management role associated.
I can get client list but i can't do nothing with them.

```java
        Keycloak keycloak = this.getAdminClient();
        List<ClientRepresentation> clients = keycloak.realm(kcProperties.getRealm()).clients().findAll();
        ClientResource clientResource = keycloak.realm(kcProperties.getRealm()).clients().get(clientId);
//all these calls give 404 not found
        clientResource.authorization().getSettings().getPolicies();
        clientResource.authorization().getSettings().getScopes();
        clientResource.authorization().getSettings().getResources();
        clientResource.authorization().permissions();
        clientResource.authorization().scopes();
        clientResource.getPermissions();
```

```java
private Keycloak getAdminClient() {
        return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .clientId(kcProperties.getResource())
                .clientSecret(kcProperties.getCredentials().get("secret").toString())
                .serverUrl(kcProperties.getAuthServerUrl())
                .realm(kcProperties.getRealm())
                .grantType("client_credentials")
                .build();
    }
```

all these call returns 404 not found

```
 clientResource.authorization().getSettings().getPolicies();
        clientResource.authorization().getSettings().getScopes();
        clientResource.authorization().getSettings().getResources();
        clientResource.authorization().permissions();
        clientResource.authorization().scopes();
        clientResource.getPermissions();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u can try creating a user in realm master and then assign a role for that user for a specific realm that u want control, and then when initialize a keycloak admin, you can use a admin-cli client and realm master for the configuration.this is example for initialize keycloak admin client

```
@Bean
public RealmResource keycloak() {

    
            final Keycloak keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance(
            "https://example.yourkeycloak.com/auth",
            "master",
            keycloakUsername,
            keycloakPassword,
            "admin-cli"); 


    return keycloak.realm("nameOfRealmThatUWantToUsed");
}
```

and then when u want to use that keycloak in service class. just use a dependency injection into service class.

```
@Service
public class testServiceClass {

@Autowired
RealmResource keycloak;

public List<String> getAllClientList(){
    List<ClientRepresentation> clientRepresentationList= keycloak.clients().findAll();
    
    List<String> clientNameList=new ArrayList<>();
    clientRepresentationList.stream().forEach(x->{
        clientNameList.add(x.getName());
    });
    
    return clientNameList;
}
```

}